# Why is P(at least one success) = 1 - P(all failures)?

Tags: probability

For questions like:

> Dion has an 82.5% chance (0.825 chance) of making a free-throw shot, Dion shoots 4 times, what is the probability of Dion missing *at least* one free-throw shot?

It is generally accepted that we can calculate P(Dion misses at least one shot) by finding the reciprocal of P(Dion makes all 4 shots), or

P(Misses at least 1) = 1 - P(Makes all shots)

But why is this so? Is there a mathematical proof for this that I can look up to know why this works-- why "Makes all shots" and "Misses at least one" are complementary?

Comment: Are you asking why the sum of probabilities across all possibilities is $1$, why "misses at least one" and "makes all shots" cover all cases, or for a breakdown into those two separate facts as suggested by this comment?

Comment: The two events "D makes all the shots" and "D misses at least one shot" are mutually exclusive and exhaustive.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#The_complement_rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event 'no misses'. Then $A^c$ is the event 'there is at least one miss'

Recall that a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on a space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ satisfies the following two properties:

(1) $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1$

(2) $A , B \in \mathcal{F}, A \cap B = \emptyset \implies \mathbb{P}(A \cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B)$

Thus, using these properties

$$1= \mathbb{P}(\Omega)= \mathbb{P}(A \cup A^c) = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(A^c)$$
$$\implies \mathbb{P}(\text{at least one miss}) = \mathbb{P}(A^c) = 1- \mathbb{P}(A) = 1- \mathbb{P}(\text{no misses})$$

Comment: @Alain Remillard Thanks for the edit.

Comment: So P(Ω) is the sample space, with events A and B, where B is in event space F, and A and B are mutually exclusive. That helps me understand it a bit more, but why would "at least one failure" be complimentary of "all successes?"

Comment: Well, what does it means that not all attempts are successes? This means exactly that one (or more) attempts fail right?